# Passing a java keyword to a java method

Tags: java, parameters, keyword

Can we pass a java keyword like `String` or `int` to a java method, like we do in python

For example :

```
package com.mycodes;

public class file1 {
    public static void meth1(funct){
        if (funct == int) {
            System.out.println("It was an int keyword");
        }
    }
   
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        meth1(int);
    }
}
```

**Pls help me can I do like this.
Thank you in Advance**

Comment: What does the compiler say? Maybe you want to elaborate on what it is you are trying to achieve?

Comment: If you're trying to pass _types_ then perhaps you should research about `java.lang.Class`. But providing your use case might be beneficial. Java is not Python; what you would do in Python may not directly translate to Java and there may be a better, or at least more idiomatic, approach.

Comment: What exactly is the purpose of this?

Answer (score 3):

You can pass it as a Class type, and check what is the type in your method for example

```java
public static void printType(Class<?> type){
    String typeName = type.getSimpleName();
    switch (typeName) {
        case "int":
            System.out.println("This is an int type");
            break;
        case "String":
            System.out.println("This is a String type");
            break;
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    printType(int.class);
    printType(String.class);
}
```

The output will be:

> This is an int type

> This is a String type

Answer (score 0):

The problem may encounter in this case as Python is dynamically typed & Java is statically typed. If you want to use the same pattern in Java then you will have to store the values in something like a string/object array and then return them like that as an object or as a String.
The best practice in Java is to use getter and setter methods for each variable.